# Load an image (Vue.js, Django)

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, django-rest-framework, frontend

i am working on vue and i am bringing an image through django api rest

table.vue

```html
<tbody>
  <tr v-for= "usu in usuarios" :key="usu.id_usuarios">
    <th>{{usu.id_usuarios}}</th>
    <td>{{usu.nombre}}</td>
    <td>{{usu.username}}</td>
    <td>{{usu.perfil}}</td>
    <td>   
      <img 
        src='{{usu.foto}}' 
        class="img-circle elevation-2" 
        alt="User Image" 
        width="60"
      >
    </td>
    <td>{{usu.estado}}</td>
    <td>{{usu.ultimo_ingreso}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <button 
        @click="modificar=true; abrirModal(cat)" 
        type="button" 
        class="editar btn btn-primary">
        <i class = "fa fa-pencil-alt"></i>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <button
        @click="eliminar(cat.id_categoria,cat.categoria)"
        type="button"
        class="eliminar btn btn-danger"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#modalEliminar"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-dumpster-fire"></i>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

and this is the method

```js
async listar() {
  const res = await axios.get('https://sistema-control-inventario.herokuapp.com/usuarios/');
  this.usuarios = res.data;
  this.image = res.data.foto;
},
```

and shows it in this way

[image]

and this appears in the code of the photo in the terminal

[image]

how do I get the photo correctly? because when I bring the {{usu.foto}} I get the link but when I put it in the src it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind `src`:

```
:src='usu.foto'
```

or if that doesn't work, you can create method:

```
methods() {
  getImage(imagePath) {
    return require(imagePath);
  }
}
```

Then in template call that method:

```
<img :src="getImage(usu.foto)" alt="">
```